# Как сформировать рандомный список товаров не больше указанной суммы?

Tags: excel, vba

Подскажите, как в экселе реализоватьтакую логику?

Имеется список товаров в двух колонках: наименование и стоимость. Есть порог суммы на каждый день.

Необходимо сформировать рандомный список товаров не больше указанной суммы на каждый день.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Макрос разместить в общем модуле.

```
Sub PriceProduct()
    Dim aProduct(), aResult(), aFlag()
    Dim dLimit As Double
    Dim lRw As Long, lNum As Long
    Dim k As Long, n As Long, j As Long

    lRw = 14 ' последняя строка с товаром'
    dLimit = Range("C2").Value ' пороговая сумма'
    aProduct = Range("A1:B" & lRw).Value ' товары в массив'
    ReDim aResult(1 To lRw, 1 To 5) ' массив для результата'

    Randomize

    For j = 1 To 5 ' цикл по столбцам (по дням)'
        ReDim aFlag(1 To lRw, 1 To 5) ' массив для отметок об использовании'
        k = 1 ' первая строка результата - для сумм'

        Do
            Do
                lNum = Int(Rnd * (lRw - 1) + 2) ' случайный номер > 1 (в строке1 шапка таблицы)'
            Loop Until Not aFlag(lNum, 1) ' нашли неиспользованный товар'

            If aResult(1, j) + aProduct(lNum, 2) <= dLimit Then  ' если сумма < пороговой'
                k = k + 1
                aResult(k, j) = aProduct(lNum, 1) ' записали товар'
                aResult(1, j) = aResult(1, j) + aProduct(lNum, 2) ' записали сумму'
                aFlag(lNum, 1) = True ' использовано'
            Else ' если сумма >= пороговой'
                Exit Do ' уходим из цикла (к следующему столбцу)'
            End If
        Loop Until k = lRw ' все товары использованы, сумма не достигнута - уходим из цикла'
    Next j

    Range("D2").Resize(UBound(aResult), UBound(aResult, 2)).Value = aResult ' выгружаем результат'
End Sub
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо Вам, это прям то что нужно! А если сумма лимита на каждый день разная?

Comment: Добавить в каждом дне ячейку лимита и сравнивать не с *С2* (переменная `dLimit` сравнивается с суммой - `If aResult(1, j) + aProduct(lNum, 2) <= dLimit Then`), а с этими значением

Answer (score 1):

Формула случайных букв, 224-255 это символы кирилицы, маленькие буквы

`=СИМВОЛ(СЛУЧМЕЖДУ(224;255))&СИМВОЛ(СЛУЧМЕЖДУ(224;255))&СИМВОЛ(СЛУЧМЕЖДУ(224;255))&СИМВОЛ(СЛУЧМЕЖДУ(224;255))`

Естественно `=СЛУЧМЕЖДУ(1;255)` вернул цифру от 1 до 255

Вставьте в две колонки и протяните вниз автозаполение

update: `=ВЫБОР(СЛУЧМЕЖДУ(1; 5); "стул"; "стол"; "кресло"; "чашка"; "торшер")` выдаст случайный товар из списка

Comment: Так товары будут повторяться и нет контроля суммы. Для большого диапазона замучитесь перечислять товары в формуле :). Тогда уж так:  `=ИНДЕКС($A$2:$A$300;СЛУЧМЕЖДУ(2;300)-1)`